# Embedded document not saved to its collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It seems as if my embedded documents are not being saved to their respective collections. Here's my model:

```
var County = new Schema({
_id                 : Schema.ObjectId,
name                : String,
biggestCity         : String
});

var Country = new Schema({
_id                 : Schema.ObjectId,
name                : String,
counties                : {type: [County], ref: "County"}
});

var Continent = new Schema({
_id       : Schema.ObjectId,
countries : {type: [Country], ref: "Country"},
});
```

...and here's the code that I use to save them to MongoDB:

```
var continentModel = mongoose.model("Continent");
var continent = new continentModel();

country.name = name;

var countryModel = mongoose.model("Country");
var countyModel = mongoose.model("County");
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.countries.length; i++) {
    var country = new countryModel();
    country.name = req.body.countries[i].name;

    for (var j = 0; j < req.body.countries[i].counties.length; j++) {
        var county = new countyModel();
        county.name = req.body.countries[i].counties[j].name;
        county.biggestCity = req.body.countries[i].counties[j].biggestCity;
        countries.counties.push(county);
    }
    continent.countries.push(country;
}
continent.save();
```

If I do a db.continents.find(), a document comes back with all the properties (including country and county) populated.

But if I do a db.counties.find() or a db.countries.find(), nothing comes back. So it seems as if the County and Country documents are not being saved to the DB to their respective collections, but rather saved to the Continent collection as regular properties instead (not embedded documents).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: country.name should read continent.name.

Comment: can you post the output of the db.continent.find()? would help with the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be too simple, but you are only calling continent.save() and never calling county.save() or country.save() at the end of the for loops.  Is that just an omission or does that fix the problem.  If it is an omission, please see my note about posting the output.